# Can't login on Kali Linux after update, only via tt1

Tags: kali-linux, login, upgrade

While running an update on Kali Linux, my machine crashed and things got bad. The GUI was messed up, so I ran `sudo apt-get install gdebi`

The system was updated successfully, but now I cannot login anymore. I get a

```
sorry, that didn't work. please try again
```

message.

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, the login works.

I have tried several different tips but none worked.
What else can I do?

Comment: Please check the solution I suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223961/cant-login-to-using-root-user-in-kali-2-0-sana-after-update/225296) and let me know if it worked.