# Can't Login to using root user in Kali 2.0 Sana after update

Tags: login, root, kali-linux, gdm3

I recently updated my Kali to Sana and I am unable to login as root using my old credentials.

I am able to login to the Console with the same username and password but I am not able to login using the GUI interface (gdm3).

I tried changing the password from console and still no change.
I also created a new account and tried logging in using the new account but still no use. I also tried to Autologin by editing `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf` but still no effect.

Comment: package `kali-root-login` - Bits of configuration to allow root logins

Comment: Also - sometimes it might need additionally editing `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` file and include `AllowRoot=true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log into the terminal (using Ctrl+Alt+F1) as root, edit the file `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password` and comment out the line

```
auth required pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet
```

by putting a `#` character at the beginning of the line. Then `reboot` and you will be able to connect.

This solution came from official kali linux forum (https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?26745-Can-t-login-after-Upgrade-to-kali-sana) and official bug reports (https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=2573)

Comment: You can avoid full reboot just by doing `service gdm restart`